# HTML5 Video Not Showing Controls

Tags: html, controls, html5-video

This issue makes no sense to me.  The code is straightforward:

```
    Dim videoLabel2 As New Label        
    videoLabel2.Text = "<video controls autoplay name='media'>"
    videoLabel2.Text += "<source src='uploads/b4c4d7c1-3946-42b3-8424-38dc4bd8b55e/version_1.mp4' type='video/mp4' >"
    videoLabel2.Text += "</video>"
```

..it's added to the Panel like this:

```
    Dim pnl As New Panel
    With pnl
        .Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(videoLabel2.Text))
    End With
    a.Controls.Add(pnl)
```

...which results in:

```
<video controls autoplay name="media">
    <source src="uploads/b4c4d7c1-3946-42b3-8424-38dc4bd8b55e/version_1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

What shows up is a first frame and it's frozen.  If I right-click on it and select "Open video in new tab", it shows up with the exact same HTML but with working controls and autoplay functioning.